# How to handle groups of objects in Python? New class for groups, or else?

Tags: python, methods

(I only recently started working with classes in Python, so please forgive my lack of experience. What I am asking previously would have been handled with a couple of scripts)

I have a class "foofiles". Methods for this class work on 1 file at a time, and attributes involve 1 file at a time.

However, in the real world I will frequently have pairs of inputs,e.g,

- 1-1 and 1-2
- 2 (singleton)
- 3-1 and 3-2
- 4-1 and 4-2
- 5 (singleton) and etc.

**(it's never more than 2 at a time)**

Some of the methods integrate open source tools which handle one file at a time, while others have specific processing for pairs of files.
I am trying to decide what is the most efficient way of handling the eventual "second file". I could create a new class for "groups of inputs", or I could create attributes for the "attached input", maybe? How do you handle such a situation?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but it's likely that you could just use a `tuple`.

Comment: With a tuple I wouldn't know how to handle properties exclusive to the pair.

Comment: It is very unclear what you’re up to. what is ``1-1`` and ``1-2``? ``singleton``? Can you please be more specific, give examples on what kinds of attributes and properties you are talking about?

Comment: It's pretty hard to give you advice with such little information; this isn't a question that lends itself to answers in the generic case (beyond *"it depends on the specific case"*!)

Comment: 1-1 and 1-2 are two paired inputs. 2 (singleton) is an input which is not paired to anything else. 1-1 and 1-2 is a pair of shoes, 2 is a Japanese sandal http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=7473029

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you might be looking for [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). There are some pretty [heavyweight implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Python) for Python, but maybe you can get away with something more lightweight.

A simple way would be to stick what I assume is the file type (1, 2, 3, etc) into your foofile object, then use a dictionary as a dispatch table:

```
process = {
  (1, 1): process_ones,
  (2): process_two,
  (4, 4): process_fours
}
```

where each of the `process_*` are functions that take the appropriate number of arguments. For example:

```
def process_ones(left, right): ...
```

Now when you have your objects, you can do something like:

```
process[(foofile1.type, foofile2.type)](foofile1, foofile2)
```

Whether or not this is appropriate, or if you need something more complex, depends on what your use case looks like.